# Use of Folders within Wordpress

Tags: directory

Is it possible to use folders within our WordPress site for the content such as pages/posts organization? Any issue in doing this?

We would like to use the folders to group related pages & content, so that we can set up tools (live chat, website forms, etc...) to route inquires to the appropriate departments based on which folder the inquiry was generated from, or being able to analyze the data in google analytics by folder.

I've been told this is not possible or creates problems with themes and other site management tools within WordPress, which doesn't seem correct to me.

Currently, all pages are located after the root domain such as acme.com/....

Ideally, we would like to organize our site like the example below.

acme.com/products/...
acme.com/services/...
acme.com/jobs/...
acme.com/about_us/...
acme.com/blog/...

Comment: Do you mean this, https://wordpress.org/support/article/pages/#organizing-your-pages ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no "folders" in the CMS as the content is stored in a set of database tables, unless your site is created with the content inside the templates and not the content editor.

A parent -> child page structure is possible and easy to organize. Simply assign the second level pages to a common parent for organizing as you detail in your question.

There is a good explanation of that relationship in the documentation here:  https://wordpress.com/support/pages/page-options/